# Wpf application shows "Cannot set Visibility or call Show or ShowDialog after window has closed" when calling from command line

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

i am calling an wpf application from command line using START command with an arguments

```
START /WAIT "" "C:\MyApp\MyWpfApp.exe" "Argument1"
```

When i run above command, EXE opens but in few seconds it crashes and throws exception with below message.

> "Cannot set Visibility or call Show or ShowDialog after window has closed"

While checking stack trace, This issue is appearing on code line where i am calling Showdialog() in code

```
var wpfApp = new wpfAPP();
wpfApp.ShowDialog(); <-- issue appears here
```

This happens only while calling from command line.

Comment: @bommelding thanks, i have improved the question.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer after doing some research

i need to call the command from the path where my MyWpfApp.exe is placed.

```
C:\MyApp>START /WAIT "" "C:\MyApp\MyWpfApp.exe" "Argument1"
```

Probably the exe file is searching referenced files in current folder